How do I use require.context in a React Native app to dynamically import images?
I'm trying to dynamically import images from a package which is installed in my project. This package has a folder full of .png files. I tried doing this to import them dynamically:
export const getImageForKey = (
  exercise: BaseExercise,
  { thumbnail }: { thumbnail?: boolean } = {},
) => {
  const images = require.context(
    '@package-name/exercises/images',
    true,
    /\.png$/,
  );
  if (thumbnail) {
    return images('exercise.thumbnail');
  } else {
    return images('exercise.normal');
  }
};

However, when I load up the page where the images are supposed to be, I get an error saying there are no modules in my images folder, and that the image I'm trying to load doesn't exist. For reference, the '.thumbnail' and '.normal' values are the path inside the package's structure to the image file.
